# android: major prob with detecting angle of device inclination

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

For a project I need to detect the inclination (pitch) of an android device. For that, I use the acceleration sensor and the magnetic field sensor and everything works fine. The device is able to move forward and backward hanging on a pendulum. If I have the angle of the pendulum/device, I can calculate the acceleration. The problem is: All that works only stationary. If the device is in a car which is moving, it doesnn't work any more. When the car is braking, the pendulum moves forward and the inclination changes, but the device cannot detect that because the force is still acting "downward" along the y-axis.

Is it any possible to detect the inclination angle in this case?

Not sure if I've explained my problem clearly. What I need is the angle of a moving pendulum, detected by device sensors.

<< EDIT >>

What I need is the correctly measrued angle of the pendulum even when it is within a moving car (please take a look at my pdf lying in my Dropbox):
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5655235/sensors.pdf

As you can see on the image, the measured angle is not correct if the box is accelerating.

Here is my code:

```
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        acc = event.values;
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
        mag = event.values;

if (acc != null && mag != null) {
    float R[] = new float[9];
    float I[] = new float[9];
    boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, acc, mag);
    if (success) {
      float orientation[] = new float[3];
      SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);

      phiRad = orientation[1];
      phi = Math.toDegrees(phiRad);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use gyroscope (Sensor: TYPE_GYROSCOPE_UNCALIBRATED)?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html

Comment: Unfortunately not available on the device. Only Accelerometer and Magnetometer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understood your problem correctly!! So you want to detect the inclination of the device when it is in a moving car...

First of all, when you say that:

> When the car is braking, the pendulum moves forward and the inclination changes, but the device cannot detect that because the force is still acting "downward" along the y-axis.

Are you sure that the device is kept vertically straight?

So, when the car is moving the pendulum will obtain an acceleration of the car in forward direction. Here, forward doesn't mean that it is directed towards x-axis of the device, but the x-axis of the car/surface. As per my understanding, you are trying to check the pendulum's movement towards x-axis, but you should check for the position of device. Hope it helps, if I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Please see above. I added some further information / description.